# Is there a new function instead of getSharedPreferences?

Tags: android, function, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I try Shared preferences for the first time and I am facing a problem. When i set my Shared Preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences();
```

The `getSharedPreferences` is red and there is also no suggestion from android studio to change it.
Do I have to update my gradle file or is that function replaced by something else?

Comment: where are you trying to do this, Activity or Fragment ?

Comment: in a fragment, should i put it in my MainActivity?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `.getSharedPreferences()` on the current context (for example `getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`).

You can see some examples here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.

Answer (score 2):

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 

Editor editor = pref.edit();

editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string

editor.commit();
```

Get String from your SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

String newval = pref.getString("key_name", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use context like below

```
private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? =
        context.getSharedPreferences("Preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code helped me:

```
SharedPreferences sh = appCompatActivity.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```